# a bizarre Connection refused: connect error in Java client

Tags: java, connection, client

I have encountered the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I'll show some code below but first, a description because it baffles me. I wrote a very basic chat program that can act as either a server or client depending on the initial button you press (host or connect). Tested on both localhost and over the internet with friends, works perfectly, as intended. I've started writing a second software and using almost the same code, but having more classes, I get this error when trying to connect to a host of the same program. So, prog A can connect to prog A fine, but B cannot connect to B. One might assume firewall issues, but here's the plot twist: B can connect to A and A can connect to B again perfectly. But B cannot connect to another copy of itself. I used the official oracle tutorials for TCP and worked perfectly on the chat program referred to as A. Depending on the press of a button, A will run one of its main class' methods (to start a server or client). B on the other hand, will create a new object of a class, either a Host

```
public class Host
{
static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
static Socket clientSocket = null;
static PrintWriter out = null;
static BufferedReader in = null;
static String inputLine;
public Host() throws IOException
    {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
    System.out.println("Server created, waiting for guest.");
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Guest connected.");
    out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
        //if (inputLine.equals("q")) {break;}
        System.out.println("Message recieved:" + inputLine);
        }
    }
}
```

or a Guest

```
public class Guest
{
static Socket socket = null;
static PrintWriter out;
static BufferedReader in = null;
static String inputLine;
public Guest() throws IOException
    {
    System.out.println("Connecting to host");
    try
        {socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
         out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        }
    catch (UnknownHostException err) {System.out.println("unknown host"); System.exit(3);}
    catch (IOException err) {System.out.println(err); /*System.exit(4);*/}
    System.out.println("Connected to host");

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
        //if (inputLine.equals("q")) {break;}
        System.out.println("Message recieved:" + inputLine);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the proper imports, I just didn't paste them here. Both programs try to connect to localhost and only A works, this other one does not. Again, creating a Guest, I can connect to the chatprogram's server. A chatprogram client can connect to this server. But this client cannot connect to this server.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? Is there an obvious solution, something I'm missing? I'm really clueless here, I literally copy/pasted server/client codes.

Edit: stack trace.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at mainPack.Guest.<init>(Guest.java:21)
at mainPack.GameStarter.grandMain(GameStarter.java:101)
at mainPack.GameStarter.<init>(GameStarter.java:27)
at mainPack.GameStarter.main(GameStarter.java:34)
```

Comment: I do not understand. What is the difference between "A chatprogram client can connect to this server" and "But this client cannot connect to this server"?

Comment: Two different programs that were meant to be able to act as server or client for another instance of itself. Program A can connect to another instance of Program A. B cannot connect to another B. B can connect to A and A can connect to B, which was never meant to be used that way, but they can make a connection.

Answer (score 2):

In your Host, you only accept one connection, and then the server stops listening. If something is tying up that connection, nothing else would be able to connect to the Host. An accepted connection should immediately be delegated to another thread for processing so that the Host can loop and listen on the server socket again. See ["Supporting Multiple Clients"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html#later) in the [Socket tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

Comment: This Host is supposed to only accept one connection. It never accepts one, only if I connect with the chat program, which as stated previously, works perfectly with an almost identical code.

Comment: Everything looks pretty straightforward, and I can copy/paste your code, add main methods, and run the Host and Guest with the expected results. It must be something in some code you haven't shown. My next guess would be that when you start your "program B" client, it stops the "program B" server before starting the client, but I'm just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: The server seems to be waiting for a connection even after attempting to connect to it. The end of my main method is never reached because Host keeps trying to accept. I'm looking at the other codes and I have no idea what could cause this.

The program starts by creating two buttons. These have actionlisteners which set a variable named "ServerOrGuest" to 1 or 2. A while infinite loop (starting with a sleep) looks at ServerOrGuest to see if it should create a Host or a Guest. All of this is the same as the previous program, except that this makes new objects, that invokes methods.

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to reduce the problem to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post that so we can see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `static` declarations from the variables in `Guest`. Same for `Host` (although if you have only one host it should be ok).

**Update**

e.g. pseudo-code

```
create server socket
while true (or quit received) {
    accept connection
    spawn thread to handle communication
}
```

Comment: Did so, that changed nothing.

Comment: Ok. Well it definitely wouldn't work with `static`. Stuff would get mixed up real bad.

Comment: You should spawn a thread to handle the communication and let the host attach another client via accept(). accept should be in a loop.

Comment: Added `static` to the variables of the other program that is working, and it still works.
As for threads, I don't know how to use them yet. I will learn later, I am trying to discover what difference between the two programs can result in this.

Comment: Oh no. No statics please! That's another complication that you don't need.

Comment: xagyg is correct. Check out the numerous networking (real-world) sample code. There is one well-known server socket but on each "accept()" call, a new thread needs to be created with its own socket-handle to 'fork' that communication. What ends up happening is that the listener on the main port is just a proxy for forking paired communication between the client and a new server thread to talk to it using a newly created socket resource each time.

Answer (score 0):

Need more details as to how this is being run and what the error is exactly (I suspect client returns a network-level connect error when attempting to reach the host) but in general there is only one port being used: 4444. I presume the error (not posted) is that this port is in use by the first programs that are communicating on that port on the same machine.

Further, the static references only allow one instance of the various sockets to exist in a given JVM at a time. These cannot be concurrently used by multiple threads possibly implemented by other client classes using these same (one) static resources.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to get much additional information out of this error, but I can tell that I tried different ports that were unused before, to no success. Adding static to the chat program changed nothing, it still worked properly. Removing every single static modifier also changed nothing to the second program.

Comment: Look at the various networking examples on the Internet that show a new thread being called and a new server socket resource being created in or with that thread on "accept()" to manage the new client connection. It is a basic singular resource issue.